# Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser re-enables itself after explicitly being disabled (and even deleted) many times

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I followed the instructions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/permanently-disabling-windows-compatibility/6bf71583-81b0-4a74-ae2e-8fd73305aad1) to permanently disable Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry.

But after a couple of days the task Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser would re-enable itself and Microsoft Compatibility Telemetry would start running out of nowhere every time.

I have even gone to the point of deleting the task from the Task Scheduler, to no avail. I am not sure of what is causing this behaviour.

Is there any way to tell the Operating System to not re-enable Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser task after I have explicitly disabled the task in the Task Scheduler as per the link's instructions?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I'm guessing you're being down voted because of your question having multiple questions inside it and also the formatting of the post. Obviously people would rather down vote than provide constructive feedback. Have a look at the [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/help/asking) page to get more understanding on how to ask the best possible question for your issue.

Comment: Same problem. Pretty sure it's being done by MSFT on purpose to harvest our data despite our wishes.